# Ajax / LinqtoSql / multiple insert conflict primary key

Tags: c#, sql, linq, insert

I try to insert multiple object in a table with LINQ to SQL

I call my webmethod with parameters, I construct my LINQ object with parameters data.

The ID is not increment, so I take the last and add 1 to create the new ID.

But I got an error:

```
"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint,Cannot insert duplicate key in object"
```

I don't know how to do it right.

Here is an example Ajax call:

```
foreach ...
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Default.aspx/Method',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
        data1: test,
        data2: test2,
         ...
        }),

        success: function (data)
        {
        },
        error: function ()
        {
            alert('La requête n\'a pas abouti');
        }
    });
}
```

And the insert (LINQ):

```
var idNew = (from c in db.OBJECT
                     orderby c.id descending
                     select c.id).First();

        // construct object
        OBJECT obj = new OBJECT
        {
            id = idNew + 1,
            data1 = test1,
            data2 = test2
            ...
        };

        db.OBJECT.InsertOnSubmit(obj);

        // Submit change to the database
        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
```

I think it doesn't the first insert works but the second insert, the select of the last ID is not really the last. Do I have to update the LINQ schema? How?

Comment: Is there a loop surrounding all this, and are you running the select multiple times within the same context?

Comment: no loop into the webmethod. Its call for each object insert, so I have new context each time.

Comment: nobody has an idea ?

Comment: the ids you talking about are primary key?